# Laravel Migration: auto incremented id as foreign key "errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed""

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys, database-migration

I was trying to migrate in Laravel with foreign key that points to the auto incremented `id` of `debiturs` table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('debitur', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('nama');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

But when I tried adding a foreign key below, it throws a "150 Foreign Key constraint is incorrectly formed" error.

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tempat_tinggal', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('id_debitur')->unsigned();
    });
        Schema::table('tempat_tinggal', function ($table) {
        $table
            ->foreign('id_debitur')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('debiturs')
            ->onDelete('cascade')
            ->onUpdate('cascade');
    });
    }
```

I have tried deleting the database and starting from scratch, but it still throws the same error. I must be missing something...

EDIT: for some reason Laravel does not automatically append 's' to 'debitur' when creating table.

```
$table
     ->foreign('id_debitur')
     ->references('id')
     ->on('debitur') <-------
     ->onDelete('cascade')
     ->onUpdate('cascade');
```

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: Laravel version 5.4.~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is looking fine may be you have a some data in your table which does not reffering to the reffered table.

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tempat_tinggal', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('id_debitur');
    });
        Schema::table('tempat_tinggal', function ($table) {
        $table
            ->foreign('id_debitur')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('debiturs')
            ->onDelete('cascade')
            ->onUpdate('cascade');
    });
    }
```